# Microsoft Security Essentials is not genuine now

Tags: windows, windows-xp, ms-security-essentials, windows-genuine-advantage

I installed MSE on several machines months ago, and these are legit systems with legit keys. However, as of today MSE is complaining.

> Windows did not pass genuine validation. Security Essentials will
>   become disabled in 28 days if you do not resove this issue. To
>   continue using Security Essential, click Go online and resolve now and
>   get genuine Windows.

What would have caused this to happen?

EDIT: These systems have been running years and never had any problems. So I know the keys are legit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Click Go Online like it says, one of the options should be to re-activate windows (likely over the phone). Explain over the phone that you have the CD keys, and those keys are in use on only one system per key (they are arn't they?). You experienced a glitch, and because you are not breaking any licensing agreements they will give you a new activation code and everything will be back to normal.

If you ***are*** using the same key on multiple computers, the answer is you got caught and windows licensing is doing it's job preventing that single key from being installed multiple locations concurrently.

Comment: They shouldn't be the same key. each system came with their cd/key from when i looked at the disks. my guess is it probably is a glitch. not sure how to pull the cd key out of the system though.

Comment: You should not need to pull the key out of the system, it should either [be on a sticker](http://www.technibble.com/articlecontent/2007/11/cod-sticker.jpg) applied by the OEM to the case or it will be a sticker that came with the software if you bought it retail.

Comment: I was just thinking from remote as I don't have physical access to the systems. Not sure if they have the keys on the systems and the cds are all tossed in a box

Comment: A tool like [SIW](http://www.gtopala.com/) can pull out the [license keys](http://www.gtopala.com/siw-software/licenses.html) that are in the registry but, just be aware that if it is a OEM computer the key it has internally may not match the key on the sticker as the key is a multi activation key the OEM uses to image the same 1000 machines (that is what note #2 and #3 on the license link is referring to)